# Rust macros: unit type?

Tags: rust, macros

The following macro:

```rust
macro_rules! generate_parse_expression_ast_data {
    ($lit:literal) => ();
}

enum Ast {
    Foo (generate_parse_expression_ast_data!("bar")),
}
```

Gives this error:

```
error: macro expansion ends with an incomplete expression: expected type
 --> src/main.rs:6:10
  |
2 |     ($lit:literal) => ();
  |                       -- in this macro arm
...
6 |     Foo (generate_parse_expression_ast_data!("bar")),
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |          |
  |          expected type
  |          this macro call doesn't expand to a type

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `playground`.
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1145b8eaf3850a53be40d837280ad008)

I specifically want to use the [unit type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html) for some of these enum cases, which by definition should be a valid type. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: random guess `(())`

Comment: Tried that; it manifests as `Foo(())`. Which is workable, maybe, but far from ideal.

Comment: But the unit type _is_ `()`, so a variant with the unit type would be `Foo(())`. Maybe you want an empty tuple-like enum?

Comment: Yes the ideal outcome would actually be just `Foo`, but I can live with `Foo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61733).

Best I can suggest for now, besides emitting a zero-sized type (like unit), is to restructure the macro so that it generates the variants in full.  For example:

```
macro_rules! generate_parse_expression_ast_data {(
    enum $name:ident {
        $( $variant:ident($lit:literal), )+
    }
) => (
    enum $name {
        $( $variant(), )+
    }
)}

generate_parse_expression_ast_data! {
    enum Ast {
        Foo("bar"),
    }
}
```